# Getting Django in a VirtualEnv to run through Upstart

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, upstart

I've been trying to trudge through the docs and examples to get my Django running through upstart so I can have it running all the time but am unable to so.

Here's my upstart configuration file located at `/etc/init/myapp.conf`:

```
start on startup
#expect daemon
#respawn
console output

script
  chdir /app/env/bin
  exec source activate
  exec /app/env/bin/python /app/src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
end script
```

When I type `sudo service myapp start`, the console says that it has started but it doesn't seem to be running.

Is it possible to see some debugging output to see what's going wrong?
I need to run my Django application as another user — i.e. `djangouser`. How can I do so?

(I've been commenting out some lines to test where the service is going wrong). This is not for production use but my internal development use only.

Thanks.

---

Edit #1:

I have wrapped both my commands into a simple script at `/app/run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /app/env/bin
source activate
cd /app/src
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

..and I've modified my `/etc/init/myapp.conf` to

```
start on startup
expect daemon

exec su - djangouser -c "bash /app/run.sh"
```

When executing `sudo service myapp start` — the application starts but the PID is wrong and I can't seem to kill it with `sudo service myapp stop`

Any ideas?

Comment: The `exec` argument should probably be `/app/env/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &`.

Comment: Hi Jkbr, I've used your solution and added the full path to the python binary. I rebooted my system and it doesn't wait for `CRTL ^ C` anymore. It now simply says that the task was started but I can't seem to find it running. Can I view the console output somehow? Thanks

Comment: I tried both ways `source activate` and `bash script` and still can start or stop. I'm trying cherrypy instead of django but should be the same thing. Virtualenv, sudo/su - Any help would be great

Comment: source doesn't exist in a /bin/sh environment, use "." instead. Checking /var/log/upstart/myapp.log, you should see a "/bin/sh: 1: source: not found".

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla did you manage to find out how to kill this with myapp stop? I'm having the same problem, stop is hanging.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
exec source activate
```

By just:

```
source activate
```

This will load the virtual environment. You should probably drop the other "exec". If that doesn't work, please post your upstart logs.

A couple of remarks:

- logging the output to somewhere else than /dev/null might be useful :)
- runserver is not ment to be stable, I see it crashing sometimes and in that case i guess you'll need to force upstart to reload, or put the runserver call in a while loop
- you will not be able to [use an interactive debugger](http://blog.yourlabs.org/debugging-python-and-django-code) like ipdb with this setup

Comment: Hi Jpic, Please have a look at my edit. I've gotten my application to start but I can't kill it.

Comment: The topic is "Getting Django in a VirtualEnv to run through upstart". Another question -> another topic.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `nginx` and `uwsgi` with your `virtualenv`. this will give you a production like environment but will also start your `django` app at start up. if you are using `ubuntu 10` you should take a look at `uwsgi-python`, otherwise just install the latest `uwsgi`. i usually start my `virtualenv` in `uwsgi` like so :

```
sudo nano /etc/uwsgi-python/apps-available/app.xml
```

```
<uwsgi>
   <socket>127.0.0.1:8889</socket>
  <pythonpath>/home/user/code/</pythonpath>
  <virtualenv>/home/user/code</virtualenv>
  <pythonpath>/home/user/code/app</pythonpath>
   <app mountpoint="/">
    <script>uwsgiApp</script>
  </app>
</uwsgi>
```

also setup your`nginx` files at /etc/nginx/apps-available/default (the file is a bit straight forward). this will help you have your `django` app at all times,

Answer (score 0):

`su` is problematic becouse it forks the process. You can use `sudo -u djangouser` instead or simply add

```
setuid djangouser
```

in your conf file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Ubuntu 14.04 and possibly other versions as well:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init# service my_app start 
my_app start/running, process 7799

root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init# cat /var/log/upstart/my_app.log 

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

June 30, 2015 - 06:54:18
Django version 1.8.2, using settings 'my_test.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init# service my_app status
my_app start/running, process 7799
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init# service my_app stop
my_app stop/waiting
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init# service my_app status
my_app stop/waiting
```

Here is the config to make it work:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/etc/init# cat my_app.conf 

description "my_app upstart script"

start on runlevel [23]

respawn

script
    su vagrant -c "source /home/vagrant/dj_app/bin/activate; /home/vagrant/dj_app/bin/python /home/vagrant/my_test/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080"
end script
```